# Making a Nearest Neighbor Search in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, for-loop, if-statement, while-loop, nearest-neighbor

I'm currently using a large if statement (that happens to be within a while loop) to search for my layer within a model grid:

```
if dzf < flheightcm(i,j,1);
    z_lay = 1;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,1) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,2);
    z_lay = 2;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,2) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,3);
    z_lay = 3;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,3) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,4);
    z_lay = 4;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,4) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,5);
    z_lay = 5;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,5) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,6);
    z_lay = 6;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,6) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,7);
    z_lay = 7;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,7) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,8);
    z_lay = 8;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,8) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,9);
    z_lay = 9;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,9) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,10);
    z_lay = 10;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,10) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,11);
    z_lay = 11;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,11) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,12);
    z_lay = 12;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,12) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,13);
    z_lay = 13;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,13) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,14);
    z_lay = 14;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,14) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,15);
    z_lay = 15;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,15) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,16);
    z_lay = 16;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,16) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,17);
    z_lay = 17;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,17) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,18);
    z_lay = 18;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,18) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,19);
    z_lay = 19;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,19) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,20);
    z_lay = 20;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,20) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,21); % probably not accounting for here on.
   z_lay = 21;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,21) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,22);
    z_lay = 22;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,22) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,23);
    z_lay = 23;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,23) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,24);
    z_lay = 24;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,24) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,25);
    z_lay = 25;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,25) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,26);
    z_lay = 26;
elseif dzf > flheightcm(i,j,26) & dzf<flheightcm(i,j,27);
    z_lay = 27;
end
no2_cumsum = no2_cumsum(1) + no2_moleccm3(i, j, z_lay, 12);
```

While this method works, it is fairly slow and I'd like to try a faster approach. The following is the code I'm working on replacing my if statement with:

```
Gz = flheight(i,j,:); % Height data
Psz = dzf; % Distance traveled from the prior point
dze = sqrt( sum( (Gz - Psz).^2, 2)); % Distance Formula
[minDist, idxMinDist] = min(dze); % Finds the minimum value of distance traveled
closest_z = Gz(idxMinDist); % Yields closest latitude ot the value given

z_o = dzf_o;
z = closest_z;
z_lay = find(flheight(i,j,:) == (z - z_o));
no2_cumsum = no2_cumsum(1) + no2_moleccm3(i, j, z_lay, 12);
```

My problem is that my "flheight" data is only of dimensions:

```
flheight(1:336,1:264,1:27,1:25)
```

but I keep getting the error

```
 >> Date_two
 Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

 Error in Date_two (line 208)
 no2_cumsum = no2_cumsum(1) + no2_moleccm3(i, j, z_lay, 12);
```

I'm fairly sure the issue is that my code continues to iterate past the height at flheight(i,j,27,t) and on until the third dimension, height, equals 28 like so:

```
flheight(i,j,28,t)
```

Which means z_lay becomes equal to 28 even though its within a while loop that states:

```
while dzf < flheight(i, j, 27)
end
```

Anyways, I'm not relaly sure why my "z_lay" variable continues iterating to 28, beyond when it should have reached the end of the loop.

Comment: Maybe `i` or `j` go out of bounds? The error message should contain more than what you're showing here. Also, it's unclear if this error message happens in the code with long sequence if `if`/`else if` statements, or in the other code you posted. It would be good if you trimmed down your question to the one issue, and only post code required to reproduce the issue. See [mcve].

Comment: It’s within the second big chunk of code that the error is showing.

Comment: If `flheight` has 4 dimensions, why do you index it with 3 indices? I don't think I can make head or tails from your code. Please make a [mcve] (including simplified data!) so that I can copy-paste your code into MATLAB and see the error message. That is the only way for someone else to help you debug your code. Until you post that, any answers you're getting are just guesses and stabs in the dark.